# .NET - Very strange NullReferenceException?

Tags: vb.net, linq, nullreferenceexception

How can I get a `NullReferenceException` in the following scenario?

```
 Dim langs As IEnumerable(Of SomeCustomObject) = //some LINQ query
 If langs Is Nothing Then Return Nothing 
 If langs.Count = 1 Then //NullReferenceException here
```

What am I missing here? Debug shows that `langs` is really just a LINQ queryresult without any results...

Comment: I did not even know you could instantiate an interface like this. Interesting

Comment: What does the call stack say about the Exception? Where's it actually getting thrown? My guess is it's probably somewhere up the stack, inside langs.Count;

Comment: Post the stack trace of the exception

Comment: There must be a problem with the "some LINQ query" part - if it's a proper query, then I don't see how you could possibly get a null reference.  If you can post that, or a reasonable facsimile, it might help.

Comment: hamlin: you don't create an instance of an interface, the linq query results in an anomynous object that implements the interface.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The exception is probably coming from the evaluation of your LINQ query. LINQ queries are evaluated in a lazy fashion: that is, no code is actually executed until you actually *use* the value.

For example, if you have the following (I don't know the LINQ syntax for VB, so this is C# but the same thing applies):

```
string str = null;
IEnumerable<char> chs = from ch in str select ch;
if (chs.Count() == 0) // NullReferenceException here
```

Also, you will never get a `null` returned from the creation of the LINQ query so your `If langs Is Nothing` check is not needed.

Comment: @ropstah: Can you post the actual LINQ query and the stack trace then?

Comment: I did actually, and there was something horribly wrong. An entire object was missing in the query, so you were totally right in your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Because langs won't be evaluated until it is accessed, you can force the evaluation by converting to a list:

```
 Dim langs As IEnumerable(Of SomeCustomObject) = //some LINQ query 
 Dim langsList as List(Of SomeCustomObject) = langs.ToList()
 If langsList Is Nothing Then Return Nothing  
 If langsList.Count = 1 Then //NullReferenceException here
```

Comment: This doesn't work obviously, because the `NullReferenceException` moves to the second line where `langs.ToList()` is called.

Comment: @ropstah, can you put the actual code up? If langs is a LINQ query result, it shouldn't evaluate to null when doing .ToList(). Worse case you'd end up with an empty list.